# I don't know what to do with my Number Guess Code

Tags: python

Somewhat new to Python, I have everything else down except for everything after the while statement. Please help!

I don't know what to do after this

```
while y > x or y < x:
 if y == x:
   print ("You got it, " + Name + "!")
else:
if (y < x):
  print ("Higher!")
else:
  print ("Lower!")
  break


import random
print("Hey, what's your name?")
Name = input("")
print ("What do you want to be the maximum number?")
maximnum = int(input(""))
print("I just thought of a number between 1 and " + str(maximnum) + ", can you guess it " + Name + "?")
y = input("")
x = random.randint(1,maximnum)
print (x)
while y > x or y < x:
if y == x:
print ("You got it, " + Name + "!")
else:
if (y < x):
  print ("Higher!")
else:
  print ("Lower!")
  break
```

It just keeps running and doesn't stop

Comment: The location of `break` seems to be incorrect. You probably wants to quit from loop when `y==x`.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. But assuming you've done this so the code runs, the reason it runs forever is because you never change `x` or `y` inside the loop, so the condition, if it's true once (as is almost certain), will forever be true. [Also, the `if y == x` will never be true inside the loop.]

Comment: No incrementation - infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition for your while loop is `y>x or y<x` which is equivalent to `y!=x`. If at any point `y` *is* equal to `x`, the loop will end. From the looks of your code sample, neither `x` nor `y` change within the loop, so if it enters with them being unequal, it will never exit. One solution would be to add an extra input line inside of the loop

```
while y != x:
    if (y < x):
        print ("Higher!")
    else:
      print ("Lower!")
    y = input('Guess again... ')
print ("You got it, " + Name + "!")
```

Comment: I input this into my code, but no matter what the random number is it only displays "Lower!" For example, the random number is 8 and I input 1 as my guess, and it displays "Lower!" even though it really isn't

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is the output of `input()` is a string, not an integer. You should use `y = int(input('Guess again...'))` to cast it as an integer and then compare it to `x`. Without that you should have hit a TypeError before getting into the loop, so that may not be the issue, but it's worth trying.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for your help on this, i really appreciate it.